# Can't deploy mongo container to testing cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I'm trying to add a mongo pod to a namespace on a testing cluster but the status of the container is stuck on "ContainerCreating".

I have created a configMap yaml for mongo:

```
kind: ConfigMap 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: example-configmap 
data:
  # Configuration values can be set as key-value properties
  database: mongodb
  database_uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
```

And i also tried to mount the ConfigMap to volumes in the Pod yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mongo
      image: mongo
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /example
          name: config
  volumes:
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: mongo-configmap
      items:
        - key: mongo-configmap
          path: example.config
```

Answer (score 0):

It is waiting to mount the volume into the container which is not specified correctly in your example.

`key` in `items` is an individual item in the config map. It should be either `database` or `database_url`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mongo
      image: mongo
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /example
          name: config
  volumes:
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: example-configmap
      items:
        - key: database_url
          path: example.config
```

This will mount a file in path `/example/example.config` with value as `mongodb://localhost:27017`.

Read more info here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's still not working,i'm assuming that the mountPath it's not correct.

Comment: @lannis, updated the answer, config map name was incorrect - it should be `example-configmap`

Comment: Still the same issue :/ i have no clue what's going on